# Print to file all data types (logger)

Tags: java, logging

I have a class file with a method that takes a string argument and outputs to a file:

```
public static void logger(String content) {

    FileOutputStream fop = null;
    File file;
    //content = "This is the text content";


    try {

        file = new File("logs.txt");
        fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        // get the content in bytes
        byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();

        fop.write(contentInBytes);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fop != null) {
                fop.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to add trace logging to many files using this method and it involves not just String data types, but also doubles etc... I'm not sure how i'd go about including doubles/ints into this method and outputting.

I'm quite new to Java so apologies if this is actually quite a trivial task!

Comment: BTW Most of this code isn't needed and closing a file on every log is very expensive. If you are new to Java I suggest uisng one of the standard loggers. there is at least 5 popular ones including one bult in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a second method that takes `Object` as a parameter.

```
public static void logger(Object content) {
    logger(content.toString());
}
```

This method delegates to your earlier method the logging of the string representation of your object, regardless its type.

Now you can call `logger()` on strings (ex, `logger("The answer")`, as well as any other type (ex, `logger(42)`).

Note that boxing (wrapping a primitive type, such as `int`, into an object, such as `Integer`) happens automatically.

If you aim at printing more than one object at a time, you have to provide a method that takes varargs array.

```
public static void logger(Object... objects) {
    String msg = Stream.of(objects).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Calling `logger("The answer is ", 42)` will print "The answer is 42".

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `String` representation of doubles, longs, etc by using their corresponding wrapper class.

Example:

```
double doubVar = 12.643;
Logger.logger( Double.toString( doubVar ) );
```

or for integers:

```
int i = 2;
Logger.logger( Integer.toString( i ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... but what if I wanted for example:    Logger.logger("Value is:     ", Double.valueOf(doubVar).toString());

Comment: @arsenal88 From that point on it'S a simple String concatenation. The `toString()` method **returns** the String and you are free to do whatever you want  with it. So you could do  something like: `Logger.logger( "Value is: " + Double.valueOf(val).toString())`. Notice the `+` operator used to concatenate the strings.